# How can I specify which Python version poetry should create venv?

Tags: python, package, version, package-managers, python-poetry

I started using [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) recently. I really like straightforward package management, but I can’t seem to resolve one thing: The Python version it should use. I have Python 3.9 and 3.7 on my machine. 3.7 is higher in priority in system environmental variables - so that might be the reason of the issue.

But let’s get back to example. Part of my `pyproject.toml` file looks like this:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "3.9.2"
pandas = "^1.2.3"
requests = "^2.25.1"
```

I manually changed Python to 3.9.2, used `poetry add` to add [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) and requests and then ran `poetry install`. I had `virtualenvs.in-project` set to true, so my virtual environment was created without any error in my project directory. However, when it is activated, I can see it is using Python 3.7.9 (on Windows, starting from a PowerShell window):

```
cd C:\pyprojects
c:/pyprojects/***/.venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1

(.venv) c:/pyprojects/***/.venv/Scripts/python.exe

Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

How can I explicitly tell Poetry to use the exact Python version if `pyproject.toml python = "3.9.2"` is not enough? Is it picking the first Python environmental variable, which in my case is *python37*? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Pyenv is very useful for managing multiple Python versions for a setup like this.  You can just do `cd my-project`, `pyenv local 3.9.2` (or whatever version you want), then `poetry install` to create the venv using the proper Python version.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Poetry can't fully manage Python versions on its own using the version specified in the `pyproject.toml`. You can either use a tool like [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) (or [`pyenv-win`](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win) if you're using Windows) for managing multiple versions, or you can use `poetry env use path/to/python`. If Python 3.9 is in your path or available on your system via `pyenv` or some similar version management tool, you can use `poetry env use python3.9` or `poetry env use 3.9`. You can read more about `poetry env use` [here](https://python-poetry.org/docs/managing-environments/#switching-between-environments).